# REST Assured with JSON schema validation not working

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, rest-assured, json-schema-validator

I'm working with Spring Boot and REST Assured to test REST APIs. I was trying the example with JSON schema validation but it throws this error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Schema to use cannot be null
```

According to documentation, the schema should be [located in the classpath](https://github.com/jayway/rest-assured/wiki/ReleaseNotes21). My example schema is located there. Here is my project structure and example schema location:

[image: project structure]

Here is my code. Without schema validation it works fine.

```
given().
    contentType("application/json").
when().
    get("http://myExample/users").
then().
    assertThat().body(matchesJsonSchemaInClasspath("example_schema.json"));
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your schema file is in the `rest.resource` package but you haven't mentioned that when calling `matchesJsonSchemaInClasspath`. You either need to move the file to the root of the classpath (put it in `src/test/resources`, for example), or change the string you're passing into `matchesJsonSchemaInClasspath`.

Comment: thanks, but I dont get, you mean copy the path?`matchesJsonSchemaInClasspath("/src/test/java/rest/resource/asset_schema.json")

Comment: No, leave the call to `matchesJsonSchmeaInClasspath` as-is and move the file either into `src/test/resources` or into `src/test/java`.

Answer (score 0):

When you execute your test cases, your complete src/test folder gets compiled and it stores all compiled files inside target/test-classes file, so in your case as you kept your json file inside the src/test/resources, a copy of that file will be created inside the target/test-classes folder and matchesJsonSchemaInClasspath method use that file at the time execution(you can validate by going to target/test-classes folder after you test execution).