# RestAssured: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Schema to use cannot be null?

Tags: java, rest-assured, web-api-testing, rest-assured-jsonpath

I need to compare my api tests response against an external JSON file.

Seem to be seeing the following exception: 'java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Schema to use cannot be null' when executing my api test.

My Test:

```
@Test
public void validateAgainstJsonFile() {
    given()
            .spec(footballCompetitions_requestSpecification)
            .when().get(EndPoint.AREAS + "2014")
            .then()
            .assertThat()
            .body(matchesJsonSchemaInClasspath("footballCompetitions.json"));
}
```

My projects structure looks like the following:

https://ibb.co/M62rHyF

Stack trace:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Schema to use cannot be null

    at io.restassured.module.jsv.JsonSchemaValidator.validateSchemaIsNotNull(JsonSchemaValidator.java:270)
    at io.restassured.module.jsv.JsonSchemaValidator.access$300(JsonSchemaValidator.java:75)
    at io.restassured.module.jsv.JsonSchemaValidator$JsonSchemaValidatorFactory.create(JsonSchemaValidator.java:281)
    at io.restassured.module.jsv.JsonSchemaValidator.matchesJsonSchema(JsonSchemaValidator.java:166)
    at io.restassured.module.jsv.JsonSchemaValidator.matchesJsonSchemaInClasspath(JsonSchemaValidator.java:117)
    at apiTests.footballData.CompetitionsGetTest.validateAgainstJsonFile(CompetitionsGetTest.java:195)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:124)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:583)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:719)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:989)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:125)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:109)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:648)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:505)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:455)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:450)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:415)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:364)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:84)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1208)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1137)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1049)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1017)
    at org.testng.IDEARemoteTestNG.run(IDEARemoteTestNG.java:73)
    at org.testng.RemoteTestNGStarter.main(RemoteTestNGStarter.java:123)
```

Comment: can u paste your stack trace?

Comment: could do you check that the response of your endpoint request and the json file are not null?

Comment: I have the same issue i tried by going with this [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33424594/rest-assured-with-json-schema-validation-not-working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33424594/rest-assured-with-json-schema-validation-not-working)

Comment: I tried the following, didnt seem to work, I have attached my stack trace to the master ticket.

Answer (score 4):

Try creating a folder under `test` called `resources` and moving there the file `footballCompetitions.json` something like: **/test/resources/footballCompetitions.json**

```
  test
    └───  java
    └───  resources
         └─── footballCompetitions.json
```

Then `.body(matchesJsonSchemaInClasspath("footballCompetitions.json"));` should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the file path is right? 
Move this file to: `/test/resources/`

or use absolute path like below:     `.body(matchesJsonSchemaInClasspath("/src/test/java/apitests/footballData/footballCompetitions.json"));`

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was my mistake, i.e I did not save the file in the proper format. The file was saved as **xyz.json.txt**. Please ensure that the file is saved in the correct format.
It will work.

Answer (score 0):

Save json file in Resource Folder and it will work

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/InBUp.png)

String Jsonpaths="Examples.json";

assertThat(RESPONSEBODY,matchesJsonSchemaInClasspath(Jsonpaths));

Answer (score 0):

Place the JSON-Schema file under Target classPath:

[image]

Comment: wouldnt this file get deleted on a fresh build ?

Answer (score -1):

This error is related to your schema which you are inserting into

```
matchesJsonSchemaInClasspath()
```

First, try to check that your schema JSON may have some null value.
You can remove those from the JSON schema file and can check it again.